# ES8 - Why have padStart/padEnd methods?

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand the reasoning behind the support for these 2 methods in ES8. [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) for example - this can be achieved either using concat, replace, repeat.

So is it just to have a cleaner way of achieving this because this could be a common use-case or this is more efficient than current alternatives?

Edit: It would help to know why a question is down voted - was the question too opinionated/broad to ask?

Comment: But `.padEnd()` *can't* be achieved with *just* `.concat()` or `.repeat()`, you'd need extra code to test the length, etc., for which many people have written their own function, so having it built in to the language saves having to do that. (Incidentally, I didn't down-vote, but I voted to close as too opinion-based.)

Comment: *padStart* is frequently paired with *slice*: `('0' + n).slice(-2)`. But numbers must still be cast to string: `('' + n).padStart(2, '0')` is more to type. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just for convenience. There are a huge amount of functions that could be done using other low level means - but when written poorly they result in bugs, or inefficient code. Everyone wins when the language adds support for something people often do.

To exaggerate your example - languages don't **need** for loops either. You can generally write the same sort of code with a while loop. People don't **need** ternaries - they can be done with a standard if statement. In both of the examples people would generally need to write more code to achieve the same effect - but why make the coder do that?

I would reverse the question - why do you think they *shouldn't* include padEnd?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the rationale, that's all, seems like I shouldn't have tried. jQuery was needed, till we didn't need it anymore. Fair enough.

Comment: That's fair enough. Javascript, like python or any other languages, grows by watching the way people use it and the frameworks everyone includes. This is just a small part of that evolution. I'm sure you'll find it handy to be able to just call padEnd when you need to as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is asking for usecases of padstart, padend functions, i.e what prompted for these to be included in ecmascript.

1. As pointed above, they are helper functions that let you achieve
   more with less code.
2. Displaying tabular data in a monospaced font.
3. Adding a count or an ID to a file name or a URL: 'file 001.txt'.
4. Aligning console output: 'Test 001: ✓'.
5. Printing hexadecimal or binary numbers that have a fixed number of digits: '0x00FF'

You can read more about its usecase/applications here :

- http://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_string-padding.html
- https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/07/12/javascript_spec_straps_on_padding/